In VUE, unable to update child component, data passed using provide / inject
In the following code, on entering data in the input fiend in the ChildComponent, myName should be be updated the ParentComponent and this is supposed to reflect in the ChildComponent as well. But that is not happening here. Can anybody help me to fix this problem.
##ParentComponent.vue##

<template>
  <child-component />
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return {
      myName: 'Parent Component'
    }
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      myName: this.myName,
      setName: this.setMyName
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setMyName(name){
      this.myName = name;
    }
  }
}
</script>

##ChildComponent.vue##

<template>
    <ul>
        <li><b>I am {{myName}}</b></li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" v-model="name" @input="setName(name)">
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    inject: ['myName', 'setName'],
    emits: ['set-name'],
    data(){
        return {
            name: null
        }
    }
}
</script>


You didn't mention which version you're able to use. I took the liberty of creating a working version using Vue 3.4 and the composition API. This allows you to dramatically simplify the code while improving clarity.
ParentComponent.vue
<script setup>
import {ref} from "vue"
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent.vue"

const name = ref("Parent Component")
</script>

<template>
  {{name}} (parent)
  <child-component v-model="name" />
</template>

ChildComponent.vue
<script setup>
const name = defineModel()

function update(event) {
  name.value = event.target.value
}
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li><b>I am {{name}} (child)</b></li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" :value="name" @input="update">
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>


Provided value isn't inherently reactive, unless this is explicitly done. And myName: this.myName is the same as myName: 'Parent Component' regardless of Vue reactivity, because this.myName is a primitive value, this is the only way it can work in JS.
In order to make it reactive, it needs to be a reactive object, i.e. a ref. The documentation specifically addresses this. Without converting the component to composition API entirely, it would be:
  provide() {
    return {
      myName: computed(() => this.myName),
      setName: this.setMyName
    }
  },

The use of read-only computed ref instead of a writable one prevents it from being accidentally changed by children, which is a bad practice.
